$\lim_{n\to+\infty}\int_{0}^{2\pi}\left(1+\frac{\sin(x)}{n}\right)^{\frac{n}{x}}\,\mbox{d}x$
I've been trying to compute the following limit:
$$
\lim_{n\ \to\ \infty}\int_{0}^{2\pi}
\left[1 + \frac{\sin\left(x\right)}{n}\right]^{n/x}
\,{\rm d}x
$$

I am not completely sure, but when $x\in (0,2\pi)$ then $\operatorname{f}_{n}\left(x\right) \to \exp\left(\sin(x)/x\right)$.
So the pointwise limit of the sequence in $\left(0,2\pi\right)$ is $\exp\left(\sin(x)/x\right)$.
When $x > 0$ it's easy to prove that $\sin\left(x\right)/x \leq 1$ so I think it's true that for all $x \in \left(0,2\pi\right)$.
$$
\left\vert\operatorname{f}_{n}\left(x\right)\right\vert \leq {\rm e} \in L^{1}\left(0,2\pi\right).
$$
At this point I assume I can use the Lebesgue's Dominated Convergence Theorem, so
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty}\int_{0}^{2\pi}\operatorname{f}_{n}\left(x\right)
\,{\rm d}x =
\int_{0}^{2\pi}{\rm e}^{\sin\left(x\right)/x}\,\,\,{\rm d}x.
$$
I get stuck at this point, because I can't quite find the antiderivative. I tried integration by parts but it doesn't simplify things.


Your reasoning is correct and the limit is equal to the integral of $e^\frac{\sin(x)}{x}$. This integral has no closed form and must be computed numerically.

From $\tt WolframAlpha$.

If you use
$$e^\frac{\sin(x)}{x}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac 1{n!}\left(\frac{\sin (x)}{x}\right)^n$$ you will have
$$\int_0^{2\pi}e^\frac{\sin(x)}{x}\,dx=2\pi+\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n\, \text{Si}(2 \pi  n)$$
For the antiderivative
$$I_n=\int  \left(\frac{\sin (x)}{x}\right)^n\,dx$$
there is a reduction formula (have a look at  formula $2.638.1$ in  the Table of Integrals, Series, and Products (Seventh Edition) by I.S. Gradshteyn and I.M. Ryzhik.
The convergence is quite fast thanks to the factorial. In fact, $a_n$ is the summand
$$\frac {a_{n+1}}{a_n} \sim \frac{1}{n}-\frac{3}{2 n^2}+\frac{7}{4
   n^3}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^4}\right)$$
Edit
Even if it does not mean anything, the value $8.6962484128213546878$ is (thanks to the $ISC$) quite close to
$$\frac{50\, i}{\sqrt{673}}\left(\psi \left(-\frac{3+i
   \sqrt{673}}{31}\right)-\psi \left(-\frac{3-i\sqrt{673}}{31}\right)\right)$$ the absolute error being $1.562\times 10^{-7}$

+1 Quite fine and useful.
